# How to edit lock screen Cinnamon?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

In my Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon, the lock screen and the login screen are vastly different (unlike in Ubuntu Unity). I like aspects of both. For the login screen, I like the pretty design and the shifting backgrounds, and the options given for me to shut down/restart or change the background but I wish it had the time and date being displayed. On the other hand, for the lock screen, I don't really like much of it at all. It doesn't have the background shifting and nice password prompt as the login screen does. However, it does have the date and time. How can I essentially merge these two together to create a login and lock screen for myself? I'm assuming I would have to do some tinkering in the source code, and that is why I'm posting, as I do not know how to do so.

Answer (score 4):

In `Menu:System Settings:Login Window` you can chose your theme. Assuming you have 'Mint-X', you can edit the settings of this theme:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/mdm/html-themes/Mint-X/slideshow.conf
```

and edit the list of images randomly used at the login screen
cheers

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it won't be easy to harmonise your lock screen and your login screen. There has been some initiative to add this kind of functionality, but no real progress appears to have been made:
https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/4322
https://blueprints.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+spec/login-screen-lock

I guess we should find more like-minded people, so our voice gets heard.

Comment: In my case, I want the lock screen background and login screen background the same, and the desktops screen background different. I thought Linux was all about customization :/

Answer (score 1):

Menu > Preferences > Scroll down to screensaver. Click on screensaver on bottom left you will see lock screen when screen saver is active. Uncheck the box.